# Celery: Can i get apply_async options when task excecutes?

Tags: python, celery

I'm trying to send task to celery with custom option arguments, like:

```
task.apply_async(args=args, kwargs=kwargs, retry_policy={'max_retries': 18})
```

But when task executes no options are available. So for example if some exception occurs, i can't write it to log.
On the other side, i see that options are working, because passing a 'expires' argument with past date results to task not being executed.